# Flutter :How to solve flutter_svg pub get failed error?

Tags: flutter, dart

when I install flutter_svg: ^0.18.0 in pubspec.yaml I got error , how to solve this error ?

Pkg url  :
[Click here to view flutter_svg Pkg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

Error :

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.17.5.

Because detox depends on flutter_svg >=0.18.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.18.0-6.0.pre <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because detox depends on flutter_svg >=0.18.0 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.18.0-6.0.pre <2.0.0, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

flutter version :

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (12 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The version of `flutter_svg` (0.18.0) can only work with versions of `flutter` from `1.18.0-6.0.pre` above. So you'll have to use a lower version of the `flutter_svg` package.

Try flutter_svg version 0.17.4

replace

```
flutter_svg: ^0.18.0
```

with

```
flutter_svg: ^0.17.4
```

in your `pubspec.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

- First, open your **pubspec.yaml** file.
- Click ***Pub outdated*** menu at the top right corner. If are using **android studio** IDE.

After a couple of seconds later you will see a list of the **package names** with **version numbers** as tabular view.

- Update **flutter_svg: x.x.x** with the latest version number under ***dependencies***.
- Also, you have to update **flutter_launcher_icons: x.x.x** version under ***dev_dependencies*** as well.
- Click, ***Pub get*** the menu for update.

After successful getting all packages. **Run** your App and enjoy happy coding. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Upgrade flutter_svg: ^0.18.0** then build success
(Add manually and run pub get)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28162035)

Comment: okay thank. I will posted another answers  to include it.